# How to calculate the frequency of the analog information signal? [FM]

Tags: frequency-modulation

How to calculate the frequency of the information signal from the follow spectrum diagram (it contains only one frequency)? Information signal is also called as original signal but i'm not sure.

[image]

Comment: Isn't this almost the same question you asked yesterday? It's solved in the same way.

Comment: @MBaz Are you sure it's the same thing? I thought the bandwidth is different from the information signal frequency

Comment: It would have been great to see some evidence of the approach followed to answer the question so far, especially if both questions are homework.

Comment: Well maybe Fmax-Fmin = 98.05 MHz - 97.95 MHz = 100 kHz ? I'm not sure though. Is bandwidth the same thing? thats all i need to know.. else i'd like some info, not particularly the answer.

Comment: @ss221Can you clarify what do you mean by "frequency of the information signal"?

Comment: @MBaz I think its called as original signal too